# Data saved in IndexedDB is not persisted

Tags: javascript, typescript, web, persistence, indexeddb

I created a small web application to learn different web technologies (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc.). Since, I would like to store data and perform some operations on it, I made use of IndexedDB. I am able to create a database and even perform insert, update, get & delete operations on it.

The issue remains when I close the browser and/or reload the page. I notice that the database doesn't exist anymore and all my data are lost.

Is there any way to "persist" the data, such that it won't be lost when the browser or the tab is closed ?

The creation of the IndexedDB is done as such:

```
let db = null;

function create_db(nameDB, stores) {
    const request = window.indexedDB.open(nameDB, 1);

    request.onerror = function(event) {
        console.log("Problem opening DB.")
    }
    request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
        db = event.target.result;
        const store = db.createObjectStore(stores, {keyPath: 'id'});

        store.transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
            console.log("Persons store successfully completed;")
        }

    }
    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
        db = event.target.result;
        console.log("Successfully opened DB.")

        insert_record(nameStorePersons, persons);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

The code used to insert records:

```
function insert_record(nameStore, records) {
    if (db) {
        const insert_transaction = db.transaction(nameStore, 'readwrite');
        const store = insert_transaction.objectStore(nameStore);

        insert_transaction.onerror = function () {
            console.log("Problem with transactions.");
        }
        insert_transaction.oncomplete = function () {
            console.log("All transactions complete.");
        }

        records.forEach(record => {
            let request = store.add(record);

            request.onerror = function(event) {
                console.log("Could not add: ", record);
            }

            request.onsuccess = function(event) {
                console.log("Successfully added: ", record);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The name of the database and store:

```
const nameOfDB = 'LocalDB';
const nameStorePersons = 'persons';
```

Example of the data that is inserted:

```
const persons = [
        {
            "id" : "d1",
            "filename" : "documents/d1.pdf",
            "status" : "Pending"
        },
        {
            "id" : "d2",
            "filename" : "documents/d2.pdf",
            "status" : "Testing"
        }]
```

Comment: @AndrewParks hope the code snippets are sufficient. Every time the page is reloaded or closed, all the data is gone. Could this be related to the OS, or is IndexedDB not designed to persist data ?

Comment: The whole point of IndexedDB is to persist data. There must be something wrong with your particular code - probably something related to not waiting for a Promise to complete. The snippets are still missing vital parts of the code, such as how you are getting your db connection. Please make a fully functional self-contained example that demonstrates a failure to persist.